# How to ignore hidden data when importing from Excel

Tags: r, excel, gdata, xlconnect

I have a collection of excel files which I am importing into `R`.

The files contain hidden data which I would like to disregard -- eg, simply not importing it, or importing it with a flag indicating it was hidden so that I can then drop it.

The files contain two types of hidden data:

- **Complete sheets** are hidden
- **Specific Rows** within a sheet are hidden.

**Is there a way to identify when data in excel is hidden?**

*Right now I am using the `gdata` package, but am happy to use `XLConnect` or other package*

Sample Code:

```
library(gdata)
xlsfile <- "test.xls"

# grab all the sheet names. 
# This is giving me both hidden & non-hidden sheets.  I would like only the latter
sheets <- sheetNames(xlsfile)

# read in the xls file, by sheet 
xlData <- 
  lapply(sheets, function(s) 
      read.xls(xlsfile, sheet=s, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

*if needed, I can create a dummy `xls` file and post it.*

Comment: My commiseration for being stuck in this circle of hell. I think it might be easier to do this from the other end, i.e., write a VBA script that exports non-hidden data as CSV. But I cannot offer more specific advice, as I would reject these files on principle.

Comment: You probably already know this but you can check if visible before copying data:  if Sheets(ws).Visible = false then  copy...

Comment: @PortlandRunner Is the `visible` flag something that is (or could be) exported?

Comment: Thanks @Roland.   If only rejecting the files were an option, but the data inside is critical.  Going the VBA route might end up being the most direct

Answer (score 2):

`XLConnect` has a nice function called `isSheetHidden` which does what you want. Assuming `Sheet2` is hidden:

```
library(XLConnect)
xlsfile <- "Book1.xls"
wb <- loadWorkbook(xlsfile, create = TRUE)
isSheetHidden(wb, "Sheet1") # FALSE
isSheetHidden(wb, "Sheet2") # TRUE
```

In `gdata` you would have to write your own function that calls the underlying perl package to access the sheet property, but it is possible.

Comment: Thats great, thanks!  now if only they had something similar for rows...?

Comment: Yeah, `isHidden` doesn't work for rows. So, `XLConnect` wraps HFFS (Horrible Spreadsheet Format), which is a nice Java library. The `XLConnect` wrapper is [posted to Github](https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect-java). The [API for HFFS seems to indicate that they have a `getHidden` for rows](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/ColumnInfoRecord.html#getHidden%28%29). It may not be that hard to slightly edit the wrapper so you expose the `getHidden` function. You might even ask the author to do it for you :)

Comment: You can do the row import with resepct to being hidden using `rcom` http://rcom.univie.ac.at/

Comment: @Hansi Can you provide an example (perhaps as an answer?)