# How to unread hide excel sheet in R(read_excel)?

Tags: r, xlsx

Would like to know is there any method or techniques which can ignore the hidden excel_sheet in an excel workbook (read_excel).

Why i am asking is ,Have many excel files in that many sheets are hidden.

what i have tried so far is referred below link.

[How to ignore hidden data when importing from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140486/how-to-ignore-hidden-data-when-importing-from-excel)

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you want to read the hidden file?

Comment: No.. i dont want to read hideen file.@Ronak Shah

Comment: Then what do you want to do?

Comment: would like to read only active sheet or ignore hidden sheet.How R will recognize it?

Comment: @Ronakshah. Hope i have make clear about question? Both way we can look while reading eacel sheet..either only reading active sheet (not hidden) or not reading hidden sheet(ignoring hidden sheet).

Comment: You linked to a solution in your post, I don't see what additional information you need?

Comment: @caldwellst this is not solution with read_excel.

Comment: There is no solution with the `readxl` package, detecting sheet state (hidden or not) remains an [open issue on Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/533).

Comment: @caldwellst Thanks ...so it is good to know that many people will get benefits if we could have solutions.lets brain storm on that if some one will help us.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a function that will *inform* whatever function you want to use, whether it's `readxl::read_excel` or otherwise. (I've tested this with a couple of `.xlsx` files, but nothing extensive.)

This requires the `xml2` package.

```r
xlsx_sheet_info <- function(filename) {
  stopifnot(file.exists(filename))
  tmpdir <- tempfile(pattern = "xldir")
  fn <- try(
    utils::unzip(filename, files = "xl/workbook.xml", exdir = tmpdir, junkpaths = TRUE),
    silent = TRUE)
  if (inherits(fn, "try-error")) stop("unable to find 'xl/workbook.xml'")
  on.exit({
    # clean up our temporary directory used to extract the file
    if (dir.exists(tmpdir)) {
      suppressWarnings(unlink(tmpdir, recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE))
    }
  })
  xml <- try(xml2::read_xml(fn), silent = TRUE)
  if (inherits(xml, "try-error")) stop("unable to parse xml")
  # everything we want in sheets is stored as element attributes
  sheets <- lapply(xml2::as_list(xml)$workbook$sheets, attributes)
  nms <- unique(unlist(lapply(sheets, names)))
  out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(sheets, function(sh) {
    # I believe attributes will always be 'character'
    sh[setdiff(nms, names(sh))] <- NA_character_
    # return them in-order, safe for 'rbind.data.frame'
    sh[nms]
  }))
  out[] <- lapply(out, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
  out
}
```

I created a simple workbook with three worksheets, with various levels of "hidden"-ness: `xlSheetVisible`, `xlSheetHidden`, and `xlSheetVeryHidden` (per Excel VBA enums).

```r
info <- xlsx_sheet_info("Book1.xlsx")
info
#          name sheetId   id      state
# sheet  Sheet1       1 rId1       <NA>
# sheet1 Sheet3       3 rId2 veryHidden
# sheet2 Sheet2       2 rId3     hidden
```

This is a `data.frame`, so you can use `is.na(info$state)` (or `grep` for `"hidden"`) to choose specific rows, either by `name` or `sheetId` (I assume these are monotonic integers, compatible with `readxl::read_xlsx` and friends).

I would *not* assume that the order of the sheets is preserved in the rows, as is suggested here. In fact, I created the sheets in order: visible, hidden, very-hidden.

Comment: ,Thank you ....! we come to know about hidden files. function is very detailed.